Changing the appearance depending on the keyboard layout
I have the following script, which checks the current keyboard layout (Ubuntu 22.04) and changes the color.
local function set_cursor_color()
    -- Get the current keyboard layout
    local layout = vim.system({"xkblayout-state", "print", "%n"}, { text = true }):wait()
    -- vim.notify("layout = " .. layout.stdout, "info", { title = "Layout" })
    if layout.stdout == "English" then
        -- Change cursor color for English layout
        vim.cmd([[highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=DarkGray guibg=#373944]])
    else
        -- Change cursor color for other layouts
        vim.cmd([[highlight CursorLine cterm=NONE ctermbg=DarkGray guibg=#44373f]])
    end
end

-- Call set_cursor_color when cursor moved.
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"CursorMoved", }, {
    callback = set_cursor_color,
})

However, I'm frustrated by the fact that it executes every time I move the cursor, even though there's no need for it.

Is it possible to hook it to a more appropriate event in the autocommand, like a non-interceptive CapsLock key press (which I use for switching), a change in an environment variable, or some temporary file (this I can set up)?
And is there a way to notify all running nvim processes about the change?

